# Hybrid Flow Client Credentials OAuth 2.0

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a web api in .net core

and its protected by client credentials and authorization flow via a separate identity server

I have certain api calls i want users with specific roles to access and thats easy

I also have system api calls that should only be callable by the client_credentials
machine to machine.

Simply placing an [Authorize] attribute isn't enough because that means any user could call it.

How do i identify the client credential account and restrict the Method?

Answer (score 2):

The token issued from client credential flow doesn't have `sub` claim since no user is present . You can add a policy to check whether there is `sub` claim :

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("ClientCredentialOnly", policy =>
    {
        policy.RequireAssertion(context =>
        {
            //Here you can get many resouces from context, i get a claim here for example
            var sub= context.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "sub")?.Value;

            return sub==null;
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Isn't that backwards?  CientCredentialsOnly "requires" claim sub?

Comment: @drowhunter . oh , my mistake , you can manually check the claims . See updated reply

Comment: better but would you also need to ensure use is loggen?

Comment: Not need , app.UseAuthentication(); will ensure user is authenticated, if not , it won't turns into your authorization policy .